# How to break out of a guard statement outside of a function?

Tags: swift, option-type, swift-playground

I'm running some code in a playground.

```
var  optional:  Int?
guard let unwrapped = optional else {
    print("optional is nil")
    return
}
print("Optional is not nil”)
```

With this current code, I get an error that says "Return invalid outside of a func". If I replace the `return` with `break`, I get an error that says `break` is only allowed inside of a loop or switch. If I don't have any other statements after the print statement, I get an error that says "guard body must not fall through, consider using a return or throw to exit the scope".

Answer (score 8):

At the top-level you can use `fatalError()` to terminate the execution:

```
var  optional:  Int?
guard let unwrapped = optional else {
    fatalError("optional is nil")
}
print("Optional is not nil!")
```

That allows the program to compile. Executing it will show an

> error: Execution was interrupted

at the “fatal” line, and

> Fatal error: optional is nil: file MyPlayground.playground, line 5

is shown in the console.

Answer (score 4):

`guard` is used to exit the current scope if the condition is not met.  You can use `return` or `throw` to exit a function, or `break` or `continue` to exit the current loop.  The problem is, you don't have a scope to exit.

If you want to use `guard` in a Playground at the top level without crashing (see [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525198/1630618) for a crashing solution), you can wrap your statements in a `repeat-while false` loop to execute them once, and then use `break` in the `else` clause of the `guard`:

```
var  optional:  Int?
repeat {
    guard let unwrapped = optional else {
        print("optional is nil")
        break
    }
    print("Optional is not nil, has value \(unwrapped)")
} while false
```

or alternatively as Martin R suggested in the comments, use a `label: do { }` scope with `break label`:

```
var  optional:  Int?
checkNil: do {
    guard let unwrapped = optional else {
        print("optional is nil")
        break checkNil
    }
    print("Optional is not nil, has value \(unwrapped)")
}
```

Comment: A (not necessarily better) alternative would be a `label: do {  ... }` scope with a `break label`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exit(_: Int)` to exit the process. This has the effect you want.

Hope this helps!